# Is There a unit test viewer for JUnit test results?

Tags: unit-tests, junit

The workflow I use has unit tests, but the results are normally written to the Visual Studio Error log (slowly). The framework I'm using is TcUnit, for PLC's.

However, there's also a result file generated on the machine running the tests (in junit xml format). So I was wondering if there is a program or Visual Studio extention that can monitor a folder and dynamically display the latest test results. Or can this already be done with the VS test explorer?

It is much slower to have to wait for the test results to be written to the Visual Studio error log than to be written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit can output its results to HTML, which can then be viewed in any web browser.

If using Ant you can configure this in build.xml, and for other toolchains that should be configurable too.

If you are using inside Visual Studio, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2969305/226958

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I should have clarified, I'm not using JUnit itself, but a test framework that outputs the results in JUnit XML format.